# Add a month column to each excel file and then merge all files into a .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, glob

im new using python and for a work purpose im here to ask your help.

I have on a same folder 12 excel files month by month that contains columns like: Product_Name, Quantity and Total_Value

So, what i would like to do but I have no idea how to do are:

1. Add a month column on each of those files that contain the same date from the file name
2. Merge those excel files into a unique file

For example:

January-21.xls:

| Product_Name (type:string) | Quantity (type:float) | Total_Value (type:float) | Month (type:Date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 10 | 250 | "File Name" (January-21) |
| Product B | 20 | 500 | "File Name" (January-21) |
| Product C | 15 | 400 | "File Name" (January-21) |

February-21.xls:

| Product_Name (type:string) | Quantity (type:float) | Total_Value (type:float) | Month (type:Date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 40 | 800 | "File Name" (February-21) |
| Product B | 25 | 700 | "File Name" (February-21) |
| Product C | 30 | 500 | "File Name" (February-21) |

After merge:

| Product_Name (type:string) | Quantity (type:float) | Total_Value (type:float) | Month (type:Date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product A | 10 | 250 | "File Name" (January-21) |
| Product B | 20 | 500 | "File Name" (January-21) |
| Product C | 15 | 400 | "File Name" (January-21) |
| Product A | 40 | 800 | "File Name" (February-21) |
| Product B | 25 | 700 | "File Name" (February-21) |
| Product C | 30 | 500 | "File Name" (February-21) |

Is it possible? Sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.

I really appreciate your help!

---

Edit.1

This is how i merge, create a csv file and convert to a dataframe using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/sq_datas"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if not file.startswith('.')] # Ignore hidden files

all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    current_data = pd.read_excel(path+"/"+file)
    all_months_data = pd.concat([all_months_data, current_data])
    
all_months_data.to_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/sq_datas/all_months.csv", index=False)
```

So, the main problem to me is create a loop for to add the month column before merge all those files in one.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Oh, im sorry for that, i will edit this post and show what i tried to do and how i merge those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a basic level, you first need to read your Excel files, such as with [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd

jan21_df = pd.read_excel('January-21.xls')
feb21_df = pd.read_excel('February-21.xls')
```

You wrote type:Date for the Month column. To add a date column to each dataframe:

```
jan21_df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01')
feb21_df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime('2021-02-01')
```

But if you wanted the file name as string:

```
jan21_df['Month'] = "File Name (January-21)"
feb21_df['Month'] = "File Name (February-21)"
```

Then to combine the two dataframes:

```
combined = pd.concat([jan21_df, feb21_df])
```

This is a proof of concept. There are ways to automate this further based on the requirements.

**EDIT**: based on the edit in the OP, minor addition to the loop:

```
for file in files:
    current_data = pd.read_excel(path+"/"+file)
    current_data['Month'] = file
    all_months_data = pd.concat([all_months_data, current_data])
```

Comment: Oh it worked like a charm, just add this line: current_data['Month'] = file
I did some changes too, split the .xls and then convert the January-21 to a datetime format.
Well done, thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent, good job with the final formatting changes you added.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely similar to what I do on a daily basis at work. Here's how I would approach your problem:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/sq_datas")
all_data = []

for file in path.glob("*.xls"):
    # Parse the month from the file's name
    # month will be something like "January" and "February"
    # year will be something like "20" and "21"
    # date will be something like pd.Timestamp("2021-01-01")
    month, year = file.stem.split("-")
    date = pd.Timestamp(f"{month} 1, 20{year}")
    
    # Read data from the current file
    current_data = pd.read_excel(file).assign(Month=date)

    # Append the data to the list
    all_data.append(current_data)

# Combine all data from the list into a single DataFrame
all_data = pd.concat(all_data)
```

Comment: Im geting the error: ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp

should I use the format string to date format like: %m-%d-%y ?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine if `month` and `year` are as expected